# Java Applet JProgressBar not showing

Tags: java, swing, applet, jprogressbar

I'm a beginner in pure Java, I was writing simple apps for android and there is a simple ProgressDialog/Bar that easily show. Here, in Java I have a problem, cause it doesn't want to show. What's wrong?

```
    @Override
    public void init() {

    setSize(Constants._Screen_Width, Constants._Screen_Height);
    setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    setFocusable(true);


    Frame frame = (Frame) this.getParent().getParent();
    frame.setTitle("game");
    frame.setResizable(false);

    try {
        background = ImageIO.read( ClassLoader.getSystemResource("data/background.png"));
    } catch (IOException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
    this.setBackground(Color.WHITE);

    bAnimation1.setFrames(background);
    bAnimation1.setXY(0, 0); // first animation is in the left corner
    bAnimation1.setDelay(5);
    bAnimation2.setFrames(background);
    bAnimation2.setXY(1024, 0);
    bAnimation2.setDelay(5);
    player = new Player(300, 300);
    gameloop = new Thread(this);
    healthBar=new JProgressBar(0,2000);  
    healthBar.setBounds(40,40,300,300);  
    healthBar.setBackground(Color.RED);
    healthBar.setValue(50);  
    healthBar.setStringPainted(true);  

    add(healthBar);  
    addKeyListener(this);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

try (Use it in the end, after adding the listeners):

```
frame.setVisible(true);
```

I hope that helps, i´m more experienced on pure java, not on android development.